# Using the Javascript API for Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm creating a new field type with the Adavanced Custom Fields, which enables the user to choose an image from the Image Library and define a point (X,Y coordinates) in this image. After defining the coordinates, the user can place an overlay video in this point. But my question is, how do I Get and Set an X and Y value in the database with the javascript API?

Comment: I think you should save an JSON array with the file identifier, x position and y position.

Comment: your problem is getting the X,Y or saving to DB ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen yes, I've made the JS code for defining the X/Y coordinates and now my question is, how do I save them to the database ... and  how do I retrieve them when accessing the field again.

Comment: well, if you use ACF tan you just populate the fields, it will be saved with all the other data and will be retrieved with field name..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen So if I've got the X and Y coordinates in javascript I can update the database trough the acf object in javascript ... how? I tried to update the $field object by $field.context.dataset.value = 123; But sadly it did not save it in the database. How do I do it?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen and I tried acf.set("posX", "123"); It works fine, but it does not save it in the database.

Comment: i mean just populate a field in the form..and please post some code to demonstrate the context and where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so @ObmerKronen suggested that I posted some code to demostrate what I'm trying to do ... makes sense:)

I've added the image in the new ACF field php file (class-tas-v5.php)

```
$imgID = get_field('image_url');
$img = wp_get_attachment_image( $imgID, "full", "", array( "class" => "overlay-point-img" ) );
echo '<div class="overlay-point-img-container">' . $img . '</div>';
```

Then I'm defining the X and Y coordinates in the input.js file

```
function initialize_field($field) {

var overlay_point_container = $field.context;
var img = $(overlay_point_container).find(".overlay-point-img-container");
var circle = '<div class="overlay-point-circle"></div>';
img.prepend(circle);

$(img).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  var relX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var relY = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

  $(circle).css({ left: relX, top: relY });
});

// Tried these two functions, but none of the values are saved in the database
// acf.set("posX", "123"); 
// $field.val("posX");
}
```

I've tried to save it with dummy data like this

```
acf.set("posX", "123"); 
$field.val("posX");
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm trying to achieve something like this to document people in an image.